# Why it says that error hierarchy is not from exception in php?

Tags: php

I am new to php world and learning from [php.net](http://php.net/) and this paragraph wasted all my day. Can anyone tell what does this paragraph tells on that reference link (http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)?

**As the Error hierarchy does not inherit from Exception, code that uses catch (Exception $e) { ... } blocks to handle uncaught exceptions in PHP 5 will find that these Errors are not caught by these blocks. Either a catch (Error $e) { ... } block or a set_exception_handler() handler is required.**

Comment: It means that `Exception`s are not the same thing as `Error`s, so a `catch` block for an `Exception` will not catch an `Error`

Comment: And what does **Either a catch (Error $e) { ... } block or a set_exception_handler() handler is required.** means ??

Comment: I'm confused as to why you wasted a day on this. Are you actually running into a problem with exceptions you need to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that the error reporting mechanism has changed in PHP.

In PHP5 you used to catch exceptions and errors with the following code

```
catch (Exception $e) { ... }
```

but now in PHP7 you need to use the following code in order to get all errors.

```
catch (Error $e) { ... }
```

Comment: to get everything in php 7, `catch (Throwable $e) {}`

Comment: And what does Either a catch (Error $e) { ... } block or a set_exception_handler() handler is required. means ??

Comment: @SunnyKhan It means you need one or the other. Pick the one you prefer.

Comment: I guess he doesn't even understand what an exception is.

Comment: @SunnyKhan I don't see how that would help anything.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I should flag the rude comment but that will ruin you witty answer :-D

Comment: @Alberto aaaand it's gone. :-)